# Need help making a calculator that calculates exponents/power without using the .math or .pow function. Using Loops

Tags: javascript, html, loops, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator that has a +-/* and the power function. I figured everything out except for the power button. How do I make a button for the power function without using .math or .pow, only using loop? I have tried everything, but it is just not working. Maybe my understanding of loops is still weak, but I think I am correct.

```js
function addTwoNumbers() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var number2 = Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
  var sum = Number(number1) + number2;
  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = sum;
}

function subtractTwoNumbers() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var number2 = Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
  var difference = Number(number1) - number2;
  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = difference;
}

function divideTwoNumbers() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var number2 = Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
  var quotient = Number(number1) / number2;
  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = quotient;
}

function multiplyTwoNumbers() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var number2 = Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
  var result = Number(number1) * number2;
  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = result;
}

function useExponents(base, exponents) {
  var base =
    document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var exponents =
    Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
  var result = base;
  for (var count = 1; count < exponent; count++) {
    result *= base;
  }
  return result
  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = result

}

function clearall() {
  document.getElementById('box1').value = "";
  document.getElementById('box2').value = "";
  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = "";
}
```

```html
<h1>Calc-o-Matic</h1>
<input type="text" id="box1"> <br/>
<input type="text" id="box2">
<button onclick="addTwoNumbers()">+</button>
<button onclick="subtractTwoNumbers()">-</button>
<button onclick="divideTwoNumbers()">/</button>
<button onclick="multiplyTwoNumbers()">*</button>
<button onclick="useExponents(base, exponents)">^</button>
<button onclick="clearall()">clear</button>

<br/>
<input type="text" id="resultBox"> <br/>
```

Comment: m ^ n is just m * m * m... n times, so you need just to do a for from i = 0 to i = n, and multiply m for itself every time

Comment: What do you mean "it is just not working?" Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: There's no need to put each function in its own `<script>` tag.

Comment: Stick to the definition: The power (or exponent) of a number says how many times to use the number in a multiplication. It is written as a small number to the right and above the base number.

Comment: Get rid of `return result` in the `useExponents()` function. It's returning before it puts the result in the result box.

Comment: @ricardoorellana Isn't that what the `useExponents()` function does?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia That's what he's already doing in the `useExponents()` function. It's just not displaying the result correctly.

Comment: the only problem that i can see is that count start from 1 and not from 0, so 2^2 will be just 2... than, is base and exponent is pass as argument, just use them, or take them out @Barmar

Comment: why do you pass the base and exponents as parameters, when asking the function to erase it directly by the boxes values; why instantiate an exponents var, and looping to a exponent other var ( which is undefined ) ?

Comment: @Barmar you are right, He only needs to remove the `return result` from the `useExponents` function

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia That turns out not to be a problem, because it initializes `result = base` rather than `result = 1`.

Comment: Although this means that it won't produce the correct result for `exponent = 0`

Comment: @Barmar is been solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems right but you have some minor bugs:

1) You need to remove `return result` line from `useExponents` function as it stops the function before it can write the result in the textbox

2) You need to convert `<button onclick="useExponents(base, exponents)">^</button>` to `<button onclick="useExponents()">^</button>` as this function reads its parameters from the textboxes. Also, you can convert the function declaration `useExponents(base, exponents)` to `useExponents()`

3) You misspelled the variable `exponents` as `exponent` in the for loop, you need to fix that

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to put anything has parameters when you call the function in your html since you don't use the parameters. I removed those.
2. You had a typo in your `for` loop. You wrote `exponent` instead of `exponents`. I fixed that.
3. You returned a result before you were done with your function and that causes it to end. Anything after a `return` won't be executed. Also you don't actually need to return anything. Removed the return line.

Here's a working example:

```js
function addTwoNumbers() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var number2 = Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
  var sum = Number(number1) + number2;
  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = sum;
}

function subtractTwoNumbers() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var number2 = Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
  var difference = Number(number1) - number2;
  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = difference;
}

function divideTwoNumbers() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var number2 = Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
  var quotient = Number(number1) / number2;
  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = quotient;
}

function multiplyTwoNumbers() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var number2 = Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
  var result = Number(number1) * number2;
  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = result;
}

function useExponents() {
  var base =
    document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var exponents =
    Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
  var result = base;
  for (var count = 1; count < exponents; count++) {
    result *= base;
  }

  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = result

}

function clearall() {
  document.getElementById('box1').value = "";
  document.getElementById('box2').value = "";
  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = "";
}
```

```html
<h1>Calc-o-Matic</h1>
<input type="text" id="box1"> <br/>
<input type="text" id="box2">
<button onclick="addTwoNumbers()">+</button>
<button onclick="subtractTwoNumbers()">-</button>
<button onclick="divideTwoNumbers()">/</button>
<button onclick="multiplyTwoNumbers()">*</button>
<button onclick="useExponents()">^</button>
<button onclick="clearall()">clear</button>

<br/>
<input type="text" id="resultBox"> <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is sound; it looks like the only issues you really have is 1) a typo in your variable declaration (exponents should be exponent) and 2) you're returning before you put the answer in the DOM element.

I additionally adjusted the code below to remove the arguments you pass to the function since you don't actually use them.

```
function useExponents() {
  var base = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var exponent = Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
  var result = base;
  for (var count=1;count<exponent;count++){
    result *= base;
  }
  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function useExponents() {
  var base =
    document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var exponents =
    Number(document.getElementById('box2').value);
  var result = base;
  for (var count = 1; count < exponents; count++) {
    result *= base;
  }

  document.getElementById('resultBox').value = result;
  return result;
}

<button onclick="useExponents()">^</button>
```